# Why global variable won't masks local variable (Both having same name)?

Tags: scope, global-variables, local-variables, shadowing

As we all know it's a standard that local variable masks the scope of global variable if both are having same name.

Example:-

```cpp
int x=10;

int main()

{

#local variable x masks the scope of global variable x in the main function.

 int x=5;

 printf("%d",x);

}
```

My question is that, What is the reason behind the standard and why global variable  never masks the locals variable ?

Answer (score 0):

In simple language, Inner variables mask outer/global variables because we can control them "easily". This masking allows us to change(read mask) the global variable in certain blocks where we need a different value than the global variable. If global variables were to mask inner variables then there would be no point in declaring inner variables.

You can read more about variable shadowing/masking in this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing

This behaviour is always dependent on the name resolution rules of a particular language. Some languages doesn't allow to declare inner variables(same name) in certain blocks like `if` and `switch`. You can read more about this here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_resolution_(programming_languages)#Name_masking